# Is the usage of "good fit" correct, in these sentences?

Tags: grammaticality, usage

Some of faculties’ research interests are interdisciplinary and diverse which are **a good fit** for my research interests.

I hope that the admission committee finds my background and strengths **a good fit** to the requirements of PhD program in Management Science and Systems.

Answer (score 1):

Other than a few missing words like "the" here and there, I would say your usage of "good fit" is correct here. However, you might want to be more specific in your first sentence: how are diverse research interests a good fit for yours?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong with "good fit" here. As one of the definition of fit goes like this-:To be appropriate to; suit: music that fits your mood.But you could also use "apt" or "to the purpose" which sounds more formal.It should not be "are" a good fit,it should be "is" a good fit.

When regarded as a unit, collective nouns, as well as noun phrases denoting quantity, take singular verbs.( adopted from English language and usage site)
. . .
"Some of faculties research interests are diverse and interdisciplinary which is a good fit for my research interests." [Faculties research interests is taken as a unit.]

Comment: thanks for reply. for the first sentence is the verb "are" correct for "a good fit" or I should use "are good fit"?  and in the second sentence do I need to use "find" or "finds" ? since after hope we use simple form of verb, but I do not know why Microsoft work underlines "find"!!!